# BigQuery WORM work-around for updated data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Using Google's "electric meter" example from a few years back, we would have:

`MeterID (Datastore Key) | MeterDate (Date) | ReceivedDate (Date) | Reading (double)`

Presuming we received updated info (Say, out of calibration/busted meter, etc.) and put in a new row with same MeterID and MeterDate, using a Window Function to grab the newest Received Date for each ID+MeterDate pair would only cost more if there is multiple records for that pair, right?

Sadly, we are flying without a SQL expert, but it seems like the query should look like:

```
SELECT 
  meterDate,
  NTH_VALUE(reading, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY meterDate ORDER BY receivedDate DESC) AS reading
FROM [BogusBQ:TableID]
WHERE meterID = {ID} 
  AND meterDate BETWEEN {startDate} AND {endDate}
```

Am I missing anything else major here?  Would adding 'AND NOT IS_NAN(reading)' cause the Window Function to return the next row, or nothing?  (Then we could use NaN to signify "deleted".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL looks good. Couple of advices:
- I would use FIRST_VALUE to be a bit more explicit, but otherwise should work.
- If you can - use NULL instead of NaN. Or better yet, add new BOOLEAN column to mark deleted rows.

Comment: Until we get rid of a legacy system, NULL is being avoided, since a lot of this data gets duplicated over there...  

So why NULL instead of NaN?  NaN has the advantage of being stored in a Java primitive double, and not risking NPEs.  

"Or better yet, add new BOOLEAN column to mark deleted rows."  

Can you just leave a column blank on a row, and fill it in later?  Or are you saying something different?